# Listing with overlay only next to content not to title

Tags: listings, overlays

I got this listing with a gray bar on the left side with line numbers in it. I want it not to be showen next to the title.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{cpp}[2][]{
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
  coltitle=black,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  listing only,
  left=15.5pt,
  enhanced,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    language=C++,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left
  },
  overlay={
    \fill[gray!30] 
      ([xshift=-3pt]frame.south west)
      rectangle 
      ([xshift=11.5pt]frame.north west);
  }
}
```

And it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the corners of the box overlay either with `xshift` and `yshift` or with the `calc` tikzlibrary by adding a coordinate tuple to the corner identifiers (here `frame.north west` and `frame.south west`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{cpp}[2][]{
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #2},
  coltitle=black,
  colback=white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  listing only,
  left=15.5pt,
  enhanced,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    language=C++,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left
  },
  overlay={
    \fill[gray!30] 
      ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=8pt]frame.south west)
      rectangle 
      ($(frame.north west)+(0.5,-0.75)$);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{cpp}{iwconfig Aufruf}
root:~> iwconfig eth0
eth0      IEEE 802.11-bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Access Point: Not-Associated   Bit Rate=0 kb/s 
\end{cpp}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

By the way: why do you use a tcolorbox when you switch off all the borders etc.? A plain lstlisting may be sufficient here.

Comment: Thanks this is working. I do not know that much about latex, I am just googling a lot and copy & paste the stuff together until it looks like I want. So tcolorbox is a result of that ;)